# What's the actual impact "release" has in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I'm studying sth about memory management in objective-c. As for the following code:

```
CFMutableArrayRef cfObject = CFArrayCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, NULL);
id obj = CFBridgingRelease(cfObject);
```

It says that after the code executes, the object which `cfObject` points to is released but `cfObject` still points to it, thus it can still be used as usual. So I wonder what impact does release function has given I can still use it after the object is released?

Answer (score 0):

`CFBridgingRelease` is a way of completing memory management for a CF object while handing the object over to NSObject memory management for the remainder of its lifetime. Thus, this object is released in the CF world but it is retained by the assignment to `obj` (under ARC). Thus it still exists and you can still work with it through `cfObject` (but you should not, because you have explicitly said that you are done working with it in the CF world).

Comment: And see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_memory_management_of_cftyperefs

Comment: thx! But I wonder if I replace the type of cfObject with a simple NSObject or just id, then after I release it can I use it any more?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Seriously, I answered the question you asked. Are you going to leech this out forever, because that's not a game that interests me.

Comment: Terribly sorry for then my mac wasn't available so I just asked you. After I tried it I found the program will crash if I try to access the released object. I think I had trouble in this question for I'm not clear with the difference between Foundation & Core Foundation.

Comment: I gave you a link that explains it to you. Read it.